# binary search tree remove function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree

Hi Ive been working on binary search tree for my school project and my remove function just doesn't seem to work. What I've been trying to do is traverse through the tree until it finds an identical pair, make that node = 1 and make it go to the bottom and at the end delete that node. So what I'm stuck on is even though i assigned prev->right/left = cur, prev->right/left won't go to a NULL value when i change cur tobe NULL.

```
bool BinarySearchTree::remove( BinarySearchTree::TaskItem val ) {

    TaskItem* cur = root;
    TaskItem* prev = NULL;
    int ind = 0;
    int depth = 0;

    if(size == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(size == 1)
    {
        if(root->priority == val.priority)
        {
            root = NULL;
            size--;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    while (cur && !(cur->priority == val.priority)) {
        if (val.priority < cur->priority)
        {
            prev = cur;
            cur = cur->left;
            ind = 0;
            depth++;
        }
        else
        {
            prev = cur;
            cur = cur->right;   
            ind = 1;
            depth++;
        }

    }
    if(!cur || !cur->left && !cur->right && cur->priority != val.priority)
        return false;
    if(cur && cur->priority == 1)
    {
        cur->left = NULL;
        cur->right = NULL;
        cur = NULL;
        size--;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        TaskItem *temp = new TaskItem(*cur);
        cur = new TaskItem(1,"");
        cur->left = temp->left;
        cur-> right = temp-> right;
        if(depth == 0)
        {
            root = cur;
        }
        else if(ind = 0)
            prev->left = cur;
        else if(ind = 1)
            prev->right = cur;
         // change it to an arbitrary value
        while(cur->left || cur-> right && cur->left->priority != cur->priority)
        {
            TaskItem* temp1 = cur ->left;
            TaskItem* tempL = cur->left->left;
            TaskItem* tempR = cur->left->right;
            if(depth == 0)
            {
                root = cur;
            }
            else if(ind = 0)
                prev->left = cur;
            else if(ind = 1)
                prev->right = cur;
            prev = cur;
            temp1->left = cur;
            temp1->right = cur->right;
            cur->left = tempL;
            cur->right = tempR;
            depth++;
        }   
        cur->left = NULL;
        cur->right = NULL;
        cur = NULL;
        size--;
        return true;    
    }
}
```

Comment: The shown code in this question fails to meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone here can determine the problem. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that anyone can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: There is nothing special about pointers. If you have `int x = 0; int y = x;`, would you expect `x = 2;` to also change the value of `y`?

Comment: Turn on more warnings in your compiler.You've written `=` instead of `==` in several places.

Comment: i'm using dev c++. How do i turn on the warnings?

Comment: but since pointer prev->left is pointing at cur pointer if cur dereferenced value changes aren't prev->left going to follow cur and also change in value?

Comment: How to turn on warnings? ... add options to your compile command.  Here's what I use as a minimum:  "g++ -std=c++17 -m64 -ggdb -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -pedantic -Werror=vla -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wsign-compare -Wsign-promo -Wpointer-arith -Wunused -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wsequence-point -Wdelete-incomplete -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wmisleading-indentation -Wunreachable-code -Wnon-virtual-dtor"

Comment: @아이스크림은메로나 `prev->left` is not pointing at `cur`, it's pointing to the same place as `cur` points to. (Thought experiment: write down your home address on two pieces of paper, marked "prev->left" and "cur". Cross out the address on the paper marked "cur". Does the address on "prev->left" get crossed out as well when you do that?)